# HTML5 Web Speech API in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to develop something off of code from an HTML5Rocks article on the HTML5 Web Speech API, which is currently only supported in Google Chrome. And because of this, my code's issue only occurs in Google Chrome.

What I am trying to do is to alert everything the user says after they say the word alert. So, alert reacts like a command and after saying alert, the code alerts everything after the word alert.

Now, I am encountering two issues:

1. When "alert ( insert message to be alerted here )" is said and is the first thing that is said, the alert does not happen. But when the user speaks something first and then says "alert ( insert message to be alerted here )" then the alert happens. How can I get it to alert whenever "alert ( insert  message to be alerted here )is said?
2. Now, my second issue is what is alerted. Everything in the final_transcript is alerted except the word alert. What I am trying to do is split the final_transcript so everything after the word alert is alerted. How can I get it so that only the text in final_transcript after the word alert is alerted.

Currently, what I am doing is transcribing everything and then splitting the transcript and alerting everything after alter. Or at least, that is what I am trying to do.

I would greatly appreciate any help in understanding and fixing these two issues.

Here is my code that does the alert:

```
recognition.onresult = function(event) {
var interim_transcript = '';
for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
  if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
    final_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
  } else {
    interim_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
  }
}
final_transcript = capitalize(final_transcript);
final_span.innerHTML = linebreak(final_transcript);
interim_span.innerHTML = linebreak(interim_transcript);

var str = final_transcript;
var val = null;
if(/ alert{0,1}/.test(str)) {
    val = str.split(/ alert{0,1}/);
    alert(val);
}
};
```

And because microphone permission is denied when not run on a server, I can have a JS Fiddle example. So I am hosting off of Google Drive.

Here is a live example: https://googledrive.com/host/0BwJVaMrY8QdcT0pIdGRmcjB5NkE/mic.html

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a joke or a terrible bug in Speech API, but in Dutch whatever you say is interpreted as "f*ck f*ck f*ck". No kidding...

Comment: @Jonathan I'm not sure either.